# Match keywords (which are neither of heading or names) with internal links

Tags: emacs, org-mode

The external links have exact match as pattern

```
file:projects.org::some words= (text search)
```

In contrast, the internal links have only header and name match pattern.

Suppose place a function with a "foo.org"

```
 (defun bisect-search ...)
```

Below in the file, refer to it, I have to name it literally 
      #+name: bisect-search

and set
       `<<bisect-search>>`
For keywords which are trivial or hard to be named, I tried

```
   file:current_file.org::keywords
```

Got but errors.

There might be a solution with elisp commands

```
   elisp:(command )
```

Could you please provide any hints to match keywords in the current file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matching behavior of internal links is controlled by the variable `org-link-search-must-match-exact-headline` whose doc string says:

> org-link-search-must-match-exact-headline is a variable defined in ‘ol.el’.
>
> Its value is ‘query-to-create’
>   ...
>
> Documentation:
>   Non-nil means internal fuzzy links can only match headlines.
>
> When nil, the a fuzzy link may point to a target or a named
>   construct in the document.  When set to the special value
>   ‘query-to-create’, offer to create a new headline when none
>   matched.

If you set this variable to `nil`, then a link like `[[bisect-search]]` will match the first instance of `bisect-search` in the file (except that it will not self-match). IMO that's a pretty hefty price you have to pay just to avoid `#+NAME:`ing something, but YMMV.